# SELECT From Result Set Using IN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm looking to create either a stored procedure or a decent sql statement to query FROM a result set.

So, I'm searching one table for room_numbers that are affiliated with user BOB

```
SELECT room_number FROM room_user WHERE user = BOB;
```

this will give me a few results, if I were to print my results from my PDO result set I'd see

```
Array
(
   Array(
      [room_number] = 10
   )
   Array(
      [room_number] = 13
   )

)
```

I could take this retrieved data, imploded it into a string and then make a second query:

```
SELECT title FROM rooms WHERE room_number IN('$roomString');
```

But, I'm sure there is a much more direct method seeing as I'm already in my database.

Anyone know of a handy procedure or statement to make to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a JOIN.

```
SELECT rooms.title, rooms.room_number FROM rooms
JOIN room_user ON
    room_user.user = "BOB" AND
    room_user.room_number = rooms.room_number
```

Comment: Good! Much better than subquerying.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use an `IN()` subquery:

```
SELECT title FROM rooms WHERE room_number IN (
    SELECT room_number FROM room_user WHERE user = 'BOB'
);
```

Another uses a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  title
FROM 
  rooms JOIN room_user ON rooms.room_number = room_user.room_number
WHERE room_user.user = 'BOB';
```

Benchmark them to be sure, but I suspect the `JOIN` version is going to be a little faster.

Comment: I swear I tried this once... anyway, works great.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how MySQL internals deal with this subquery inside IN. According to my own experiences, it seems it runs the subquery SELECT **once for each row** it is verifying the match in the `WHERE` clause. It is absurdly slow.

Answer (score 0):

### Look IN your select.

```
SELECT title FROM rooms WHERE room_number IN
(SELECT room_number FROM room_user WHERE user = BOB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first query as a subquery:

```
SELECT title FROM rooms WHERE room_number IN
(SELECT room_number FROM room_user WHERE user = "BOB");
```

But this solution performs extremely bad (it is much faster to do the `implode` using PHP).

Another SO user just posted a solution using JOIN and it is probably the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use at this point a subquery at this way

```
SELECT title FROM rooms WHERE room_number IN(
     SELECT room_number FROM room_user WHERE user = BOB
);
```

But this subquery could need more resources that 2 separate queries.